# componentDidUpdate function doesn't get called

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I've created a React component to render another component inside.when I change the select element in the parent component the componentDidUpdate function  doesn't get called in the child component

component1:

```
let ExtraParam = [];

const handleChange = (e) => {
    ExtraParam[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
}
            
const Flights = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className='col-6 col-md-3 mt-5'>
                    <select onChange={handleChange} name="age" className="browser-default custom-select">
                        <option>Choose your option</option>
                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        <Datatable Api='/api/Flights' Columns={columns} extraParam {ExtraParam} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

component2:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.extraParam !== prevProps.extraParam)
    {
        console.log('changed');
    }
}
```

Comment: cant understand your code, whats `component1` & `2` where used ??

Comment: `let ExtraParam = [];` won't work, it needs to be part of the parent's state so *it* correctly updates and rerenders so it can pass an updated prop to child.

Comment: Consider this demo: https://codesandbox.io/embed/happy-dream-so7yn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark